# Add number after variable name automatically and in one condition to not?

Tags: php, while-loop, numbers

How to do:

```
$user1_rating=0;
$user2_rating=0;
$user3_rating=0;
$user4_rating=0;
$user5_rating=0;
$user6_rating=0;
$user7_rating=0;
$user8_rating=0;
$user9_rating=0;
$user10_rating=0;
```

automaticaly with php(i will use this in while cycle), and not if $username==$row['username'] is the same as the before $row['username']?

Comment: This is why language designers invented arrays

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an array:

```
$user_rating = array();
```

They keys will be:

```
$user_rating[0];
$user_rating[1];
$user_rating[2];
$user_rating[3];
$user_rating[4];
$user_rating[5];
$user_rating[6];
$user_rating[7];
```

And so on.

Comment: Could you make an example?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? This is example enough in my opinion and is a basic of PHP. If you are completely new to it, try to following link: www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 1):

Try variable variable:

```
<?php
    for($i = 1; $i<=100; $i++) {
         $name = "user" . $i . "_rating";
         $$name=0;
}
```

Also you can use array:

```
<?php
    $rating = array();
    for($i = 1; $i<=100; $i++) {
         $rating[$i] = 0;
}
```

Comment: for($i = 1; $i<=100; $i++) {
         $name = "user" . $i . "_rating";
         $$name=0;
}

How to add constant to $$name? I've set $$name but the echo returns user1_ratinguser2_ratinguser3_ratinguser4_ratinguser5_ratinguser6_ratinguser7_ratinguser8_ratinguser9_ratinguser10_rating

Comment: if you write `echo $name . PHP_EOL; ` you will sure that output is separated

Comment: Ok but it should return 45 not the variable name.

Comment: Returns the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$$foo` to use the string value of `$foo` as the name for a new variable.

For your case:

```
$i = 1;
while ($i < 11) {
    $varname = 'user'.$i.'_rating';
    $$varname = 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you suggest such cruel and evil things ... this makes me sad. :( Just use arrays.

Comment: I agree an array is the way to go in this (and most similar) cases, nevertheless this solution can be handy at times.